# Movement keys and tab key dont´t work in Firefox with event onKeypress() JavaScript

Tags: javascript, keypress

I have the next code:

```js
function valid_num(e){
    tecla = (document.all) ? e.keyCode : e.which;

    //Tecla de retroceso para borrar, siempre la permite
    if (tecla==8){
        return true;
    }

    //Allows only numbers
    patron =/[0-9]/;
    tecla_final = String.fromCharCode(tecla);
    return patron.test(tecla_final);
}
function valid_text(e){
    tecla = (document.all) ? e.keyCode : e.which;

    //Tecla de retroceso para borrar, siempre la permite
    if (tecla==8 || tecla == 32){
        return true;
    }

    // Allows only letters
    patron =/[a-z,A-Z,ñ,Ñ,á-ú,Á-Ú]/;
    tecla_final = String.fromCharCode(tecla);
    return patron.test(tecla_final);
}
function valid_numText(e){
    tecla = (document.all) ? e.keyCode : e.which;

    //Tecla de retroceso para borrar, siempre la permite
    if (tecla==8){
        return true;
    }

    // Allows numbers and letters
    patron =/[a-z,A-Z,0-9,ñ,Ñ]/;
    tecla_final = String.fromCharCode(tecla);
    return patron.test(tecla_final);
}
```

This is how I call the functions:

```html
<input id="nombre" name="nombre" type="text" class="validate" onkeypress="return valid_text(event)" maxlength="20" value="<?=$nombre;?>">
```

Which works very well in Chrome but, when I open the same page in Firefox it doesn´t detect the tab key and the movement keys.
If someone can help me, I will be grateful.

Comment: Have you tried onkeydown or onkeyup?

Comment: Not yet, do I have to change the entire  code

Comment: Nope, like @KUMAR said in the answer below, Just change onkeypress

Answer (score 0):

Just change onkeypress to onkeydown
so you function call becomes this

it works on all browsers and correctly

```html
<input id="nombre" name="nombre" type="text" class="validate" onkeydown="return valid_text(event)" maxlength="20" value="10">
```

Jsbin link: https://jsbin.com/qodadey/edit?html,js,console,output

Edit:

to block number or numeric values to trigger the function use the condition to check for key value and return false

example:

```
  if(e.key <= 9){
  return false;}
```

Comment: I did it an the key tab is already working fine, but a new problem has araisen. I´m working with a numeric keypad, and as far as I know, they have a different ascii code for each numeric key, and I do not know how to disable them, 
because I'm printing the ASCII code and it's the same as some letter keys, and I can´t only diseable them.

Comment: @U.C use  event.key condition for your code like this

if(e.key <= 9){
      return false;
 }

I have edited jsbin code with condition

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem just adding `tecla==0` to each condition, for example:

```
function valid_text(e){

        /*code*/
        if (tecla==8 || tecla == 32 || tecla == 0){
           return true;
        }
        /*code*/

 }
```

anyway, thanks for your help